# Removing HTML tags from Python DataFrame

Tags: python, html, pandas, nlp

I have a csv file that includes html tags. I am trying to iterate through the DataFrame to remove the html tags using the following function and am getting 'TypeError: expected string or buffer'. Any help on this error would be greatly appreciated.

```
import re

def clean_html(raw_html):
    for index, row in raw_html.iterrows():
        cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
        cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
        return cleantext
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the raw_html variable to the re.sub function. Try passing in the row data.

```
cleantext = re.sub(clean, '', row['a1'])
```